# Python numpy array values get rounded after boolean indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to apply calculation only for those values that are higher than threshold. After doing it with boolean indexing, values get rounded. How to prevent it?

```
starting_score = 1
threshold = 5
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
gt_idx = x > threshold
le_idx = x <= threshold
decay = math.log(2) / 10
y = starting_score * np.exp(-decay * x)
x[gt_idx] = starting_score * np.exp(-decay * x[gt_idx])

y
array([1.        , 0.93303299, 0.87055056, 0.8122524 , 0.75785828,
       0.70710678, 0.65975396, 0.61557221, 0.57434918, 0.53588673,
       0.5       ])


x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

when applied to full array, I get correct `y` array.
when applied to part of x, values get selected properly, but rounded to 0

My expected output is

```
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.65975396, 0.61557221, 0.57434918, 0.53588673, 0.5])
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: You must specify type of x values by e.g. `dtype=np.float64`. Using `x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype=np.float64)` will solve?

Comment: Added expected output in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered `np.int32` as default type for when you create a NumPy array with integers as `x`. For getting other types in the results you have two ways:

```
# np.float32 or np.float64
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=np.float64)  # way 1
x = x.astype(np.float64)                                            # way 2
```

such operation is not needed for `y` because in is multiplied by a float type value i.e. `np.exp(-decay * x)`, so it became to float types.

Answer (score 0):

numpy automatically assigns the integer data type to `x`. To preserve your floats you need to change the type of the `x` array

```
x.dtype
# Out: dtype('int64')

x = x.astype('float64')
```

or declare `x` as an array of `float64`

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype='float64')
```